# Simpler way to represent 1900 epoch in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there a simpler way to calculate this? Perhaps via a method built-in to .NET?

```
        var time = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(8);
        var year = 10000000000000 * (ulong)(time.Year - 1900);
        var month = 100000000000 * (ulong)(time.Month - 1);
        var dayofyear = 100000000 * (ulong)(time.DayOfYear - 1);
        var day = (ulong)(time.Day * 1000000);
        var Hour = (ulong)(time.Hour * 10000);
        var Minute = (ulong)(time.Minute * 100);
        var Second = (ulong)(time.Second);
        var utcTime = year + month + dayofyear + day + Hour + Minute + Second;
```

Could it be DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(8).AllMilliseconds?

I've tried these methods

```
            var test = (time - DateTime.MinValue).Milliseconds;

        var tes2t = (time - DateTime.MinValue).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: You can just subtract two instance of `DateTime` to get a `TimeSpan` and then get milliseconds from there.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if you noticed my edits - i've already tried. the values are different.

Comment: I'm only trying not to reinvent the wheel. If there's a method built in .NET already I want to use it, that's the purpose of this question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `1900 epoch`. Usually it's either number of seconds (or milliseconds) since some reference date (1/1/1900), but I'm not sure what you are doing. Why are you multiplying minutes by 100? for example?

Comment: @Asterisk Then why don't you explain what you want to do instead of `Is there a simpler way to calculate this?`

Comment: And why are you adding `Day` (which is of the month) and `DayOfYear`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean either.  Ignoring the confusing code and looking just at the question of how to "represent 1900 epoch", you could use a simple constructor `var epochUtc = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);`

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.MinValue` is not 1900.  The documentation for [`DateTime.MinValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> The value of this constant is equivalent to 00:00:00.0000000 UTC, January 1, 0001, in the Gregorian calendar.

Which is about 1899 years before the date you want.  You want to do this:

```
double milliseconds = ( time - new DateTime( 1900, 1, 1 ) ).TotalMilliseconds
```

EDIT: As Rick suggests in the comments, the following might be better suited to your needs:

```
var epoch = new DateTime( 1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc );
double milliseconds = ( time - epoch ).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: See my earlier comment to OP where I also use a simple constructor but also specify a `DateTimeKind`.

Comment: @RickDavin Good point, I've updated the answer.